# Unable to set properties in a MP4 file with StorageItemContentProperties SavePropertiesAsync

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile

I am trying to set some properties in MP4 video files in a UWP App. I am able to retrieve extended properties without problems. However, when I try to modify and save the properties, some of them cause the app to fail.

I thought that any of the properties that can be modified through the windows explorer can also be modified programmatically but It does not work with my code.

I have found the different parameters that I can use to retrieve and save properties in the windows property page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props

I have also checked different topics like this one and I able to save properties like keyword but when I try to save the Actors (ItemParticipants) it fails. [uwp StorageFile adding a custom property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794568/uwp-storagefile-adding-a-custom-property)

Here is the code that I use to save properties

```cs
// The list of pair of key/values to pass in the retrieve or save properties
IDictionary<string, Object> PropertiesToSave = new Dictionary<string, Object>();

//Adding the property to save
PropertiesToSave.Add("System.ItemParticipants", myParticipantsList[]);  
PropertiesToSave.Add("System.Keywords", myKeywordsList[]);

//saving the properties
await video.Properties.SavePropertiesAsync(PropertiesToSave);
```

If i just save the keywords, works fine, but if I save the ItemParticipants it fails even though I'm able to retrieve them and also I'm able to set them directly from the windows explorer.

How can I know which of the windows property can be set for a video ? Is it only the properties from the VideoProperties (indicated as settable) the can be set ?

Comment: Hi, This property may not be set by code. You can get the corresponding video property through `video.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync()`.

Comment: ok, thanks but how to know which properties are settable by code ?

Comment: It is recommended to get properties that can be accessed directly by the class. For properties such as `System.Keywords`, I have not found the documentation to explain their usability on UWP. This is not recommended.